# PHP convert time strtotime working incorrect for me

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I need to convert time, use PHP strtotime function.

time have following format

```
$date1 = 12:10:00
$date2 = 00:10:00
echo date( 'Y:m:d h:i:s', strtotime( $date1 )); // 12:10:00
echo date( 'Y:m:d h:i:s', strtotime( $date2 )); // 12:10:00
```

How I can recognise is time 00:10 or 12:10

Thanks for help!

Comment: What do you require? Identify somehow which variable contains time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [date reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), a lower-case `h` is the 12-hour formatted hour. You need a capital `H`:

```
echo date( 'Y:m:d H:i:s', strtotime( $date1 )); // 12:10:00
echo date( 'Y:m:d H:i:s', strtotime( $date2 )); // 00:10:00
```

FWIW: Your time variables should be strings, with quotes.:

```
$date1 = "12:10:00";
$date2 = "00:10:00";
```

Comment: And they also need to fix the parse errors in date declarations

Answer (score 1):

You can check difference using AM or PM or use 24 hours format cause 0 and 12 same mean for time different is it's am or pm

```
$date1 = '12:10:00';
$date2 = '00:10:00';
echo date( 'Y:m:d h:i:s A', strtotime( $date1 )); // 2014:04:16 12:10:00 PM
echo date( 'Y:m:d h:i:s A', strtotime( $date2 )); // 2014:04:16 12:10:00 AM
```

or use capital `H`

```
echo date( 'Y:m:d H:i:s', strtotime( $date1 )); // 12:10:00
echo date( 'Y:m:d H:i:s', strtotime( $date2 )); // 00:10:00
```

Answer (score 0):

`h` is *"12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros, 01 through 12"*.
You want `H` instead, which is 00 through 23. See http://php.net/date.

Answer (score 0):

In the date format `h` is 12 hour. To differentiate you can either use `G` or you can add am or pm with `a`.

I.e.

```
echo date( 'Y:m:d G:i:s', strtotime( $date1 ));
echo date( 'Y:m:d G:i:s', strtotime( $date2 ));

echo date( 'Y:m:d h:i:s a', strtotime( $date1 ));
echo date( 'Y:m:d h:i:s a', strtotime( $date2 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$result = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the 24 hour format!

```
$date1 = 12:10:00
$date2 = 00:10:00
echo date( 'Y:m:d H:i:s', strtotime( $date1 ));
echo date( 'Y:m:d H:i:s', strtotime( $date2 ));
```